# NSArray beyond bounds crash in TestFlight build but not in local-app-to-iPhone deployment

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, testflight, crash-reports

I'm really struggling with this:

App has been working with local deployment to my device for months during development.

But now that it has been deployed via TestFlight, it always crashes in the same place.  I attach a screenshot from Firebase that shows the crash log. The issue is that it is a very basic NSArray out of bounds error, which presumably should not work on my local iPhone or any other device receiving the app via TestFlight.  How could it work in one case and not the other?  Any views/ideas appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Someone marked down this request.  Can those type of contributors please have the courtesy to explain why so people can learn.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, so I'll put my question here:
How is the NSArray being filled? What is it being filled with? Is the content defined or loaded from an external source?

Comment: Thanks for this.  This helped me check there were no safety checks to ensure nil values were accidentally inserted into the NSDictionary.  What can be confusing is trying to understand why this type of error was only detected via TestFlight deployment, and not when deploying locally to the device or testing in the simulator.